# How to extract certain data cell from Listview / Gridview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, listview, gridview

Hi please keep in mind I am new with `WPF`, I am using a `WebService` that returns a `gridlist[]` and it automatically populate my `Gridview`. here is the `WebService`:

**C#:**

```
WebService.Contacts Contact = new WebService.Contacts();
grdGetGroup.ItemsSource = Contact.GetGroups(Username, Password);
```

Here is my **XAML**:

```
<ListView x:Name="grdGetGroup"
          Margin="560,34,128,48"
          FontSize="13"
          BorderBrush="#FFF01F1F"
          Foreground="#FFF01F1F"
          SelectedIndex="1"
          FontFamily="/WPF Working Experimenet;component/Font/#B Nazanin">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridID"
                            Header="ID"
                            Width="50"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupID}"
                            FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Group Name"
                            Width="85
                                                            "
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupName}"
                            FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Numbers"
                            Width="60"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ContactCount}"
                            FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Access"
                            Width="60"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShowToChild}"
                            FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description"
                            Width="150"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupDescription}"
                            FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=""
                            Width="60"
                            FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button x:Name="btnChangeGroup"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Content="Change"
                                    Cursor="Hand"
                                    Click="btnChangeGroup_Click">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                                                                            <ContentPresenter /></TextBlock>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                                Value="Black" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                     Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                                        Value="Red" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header=""
                            Width="60"
                            FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button x:Name="btnRemoveGroup"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Content="Remove"
                                    Cursor="Hand"
                                    Click="btnRemoveGroup_Click">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                                                                            <ContentPresenter /></TextBlock>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                                Value="Black" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                     Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                                        Value="#FFF01F1F" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If you have noticed, I have 2 `button` for every row in `Gridview` which is built automatically as well, now here is my question how to extract the `Data` in `GridviewColumn x:Name"GridID"`? and pass it to the same row's `Button Click Event` (Which has a `method` that takes the `Data` has an input)

Comment: What do you want the button to do with GridID ? Do you want to handle GridID to be ahndled in the button's callback ?

Comment: Hey @EmmanuelDURIN, I have another Webservice Method that take GridID's data as an input and process something else. I have to store the cell's data into a another variable and use it in the method. tho it has to happen dynamically, since every row has its own data and its button, and process happens only to the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valkyry,

If I undestand/guess right, on every line you ve got a `gridList` item.

If I undestand/guess right each `gridList` has a `GroupID` property.
Correct me if am wrong.

**In WPF, in a DataGrid, each line has a `DataContext` property that holds the data of the line :**

```
void btnRemoveGroup_Click( Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var fxElt = sender as FrameworkElement;
    var lineData = fxElt.DataContext as gridlist;
    int groupID = lineData .GroupID;
}
```

Tell me it works or not. Regards

Comment: It worked Beautifully! You are my savior! :D Thank you! you deserve +100 for this :)